# Does pinning an object also pin the references included in the object?

Tags: .net, pinvoke

I have a native function that expects a reference to a struct define in C and in C# as follows:

```
typedef struct _dataBlob 
{
    DWORD   length;
    BYTE    *data;
} DataBlob

[StructLayout(layoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DataBlob
{
    public uint length;
    public byte[] data;
}
```

I would pass this to the native function by ref and it works just fine. From my understanding, the struct is pinned for me before the call, and unpinned when the call returns. What I am unsure of is when it pins this struct for me, does it also pin the byte[] referenced in the struct? Do I have to pin it to insure that the GC will not move it during the call? Is there some attribute I need to set to ensure it gets pinned or that a copy is created on the native heap for me?

Comment: `and it works just fine`.  Right, don't help.  The marshaller takes care of pinning.

Comment: Yes, it works now, but I still don't understand if this is because it pinned the struct AND the array within it, or I just got lucky and the GC gods decided to no do a collection during the native call. This is just a simple example. Imagine if I had an object that had a reference to another object, and that object had references of its own. Do all those objects get pinned for me? I guess I'm asking about more information about how the marshaller works.